# <asp:updatepanel> is not present in Asp 2.0 aspx page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajax.net

I am using ASP 2.0 web application. I have installed ASP 2.0 Ajax Extender 1.0. Then I opened the web application to use UpdatePanel. However, element is not present. I am able to use Ajax Tool kit controls like AjaxCaleneder,... Can any one tell me how can get  tag so that I can use updatepanel functionality.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example [here](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/).

Basically, you need a ScriptManager before the UpdatePanel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```